# Getting System.Net.Sockets.SocketException "Can't assign requested address" on Visual Studio for Mac (2019)

Tags: macos, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

I'm running multiple .net core API projects in Visual studio 2019 for Mac. The 1st project get started. But other are failing.

[Error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yijV.png)

Comment: You cannot run multiple Kestrel instances at the same port, so running multiple of them you should force them to run at different ports via Kestrel configuration, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: To add to what Lex Li has commented, I would check the ports defined in the Properties/launchSettings.json file. In this file the applicationUrl setting for your current project (not the iisSettings section but the section named after your project) will have ports defined - check they are different for each project - by default ports 5000 and 5001 are used.

Answer (score 2):

You may have this error when you change the default value localhost for applicationUrl in launchSettings.json file.

> If you have change the localhost value to use your LAN (Local Area
> Network) address, make sure to be connected to the access point that
> provided you the address you set to applicationUrl in
> luanchSettings.json file.

This was the issue in my case. Hope this can help...

Comment: Yes! I didn't notice the value was changed by other and spent hours to fix it until I see this comment. Thx